# Hacking Solr DataImportHandler full-import

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have been tasked with adding an "are you sure" confirmation to the DataImportHandler full import processes. Is there a way to accomplish this without editing the DataImportHandler source?

In other words, http://solr.local:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import should ask for confirmation before doing a full import.

I'm running Solr 3.5.0 under Tomcat 7.0.26 under Sun JVM v. 1.6.0_16-b01. I'm not a developer, but have done some Java coding in the past.

Best wishes,
Myles

Answer (score 1):

Make people use another interface. Don't direct users to the `full-import` url; create another HTML page where the user has to click 'OK' on a javascript alert before the `full-import` command is invoked. No hacking required.